# Laravel Ajax post return "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Tags: ajax, laravel, post

I want to submit contact form using ajax . However I encounter error fail to load resource with a status of 405 . 
Here is my ajax code .

```
    <script>
  $('#formContact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
          });
          var datastring = $("#contactForm").serialize();
          $.ajax({
            url:'http://localhost:8888/koopbpm/public/submitContact',
            method: 'POST',
            data:datastring ,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
           success:function(data){
              var response = JSON.parse(data);
              if(response.status == true){
                alert('success')
                  }else{
                alert('failed');
              }
            }
          });
      });
```

Here is my route controller in web.php file

```
Route::post('/submitContact', 'ContactController@contactUs');
```

Here is my contact controller

```
public function index(){

    return view('koopbpm.hubungi_kami');

} 

public function contactUs(Request $request){

return 'test' ;     

}
}
```

I still don't figure what error cause this problem

My folder structure 
[Here Is My Link To My Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/006kn.png)

Comment: what is your folder structure for `hubungi_kami` blade ?

Comment: here my folder structure ,

Comment: Change your view to `view('koopbpm.Hubungi_kami');` ?

Comment: remove /public from route

Answer (score 0):

According to your folder structure your view should be like

```
public function index(){
    return view('koopbpm.Hubungi_kami');
}
```

And change `url:'/submitContact',` in ajax 
And  in route `Route::post('submitContact'`

Comment: I still got error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) "

Comment: change `url:'/submitContact',` in ajax and  in route `Route::post('submitContact'`

Comment: when I changed the url to  url: '/submitContact' it will be error 404 .

Comment: how you run your laravel `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: actually I already success for another post , but im weird with this one . Why it have this error .

Answer (score 0):

Change The ajax url to

```
url:'/submit-contact',
```

Here is the route controller in web.php file

```
Route::post('/submit-contact', 'ContactController@postContactUs');
```

Here is the contact controller

```
public function postContactUs(Request $request){

return 'test' ;     

}
```

Let me know if not works